# Vector Spaces :State True or False?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

1. $A$ and $B$ are subsets of vector spaces, then $A≠B → L(A) ≠L(B)$.
2. A set containing a linearly independent set of vectors is itself linearly independent.

I think these two statements are obvious as it seem but the answer to them is false. Please Explain.

Comment: What is $L(A)$?

Comment: For part $2$:  What about $A=\{\vec v,2\,\vec v\}$?

Comment: @DanielLittlewood L(A)- linear combination of vectors in A

Comment: @lulu The set you mentioned contains linearly dependent set of vectors.

Comment: True...so what?  You asked for a set that contained  a linearly independent set.  Mine does...namely $\vec v$ (trusting it's non-zero).  But the entire set is not linearly independent...contradicting the statement of $2$.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove that a statement is false, providing a counter example is enough.

For 1. I suggest you look, for $V$ some vector space of non-null dimension of your choice, $A=V$ and $B=V\setminus \{0\}$ (if your sets are required to be finite, which is not specified here, look two a basis and one additional non-null vector for each)

For 2. I suggest you look at some vector space $V$ (if your set is requires to be finite, which is not specified here, look at a basis and an additional non-null vector)

Answer (score 0):

> (1) Consider vector space $\mathbb R^3$.

Now,consider $P$={$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      1\\
      0\\
0
    \end{array}
\right] $,$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      0\\
      1\\
0
    \end{array}
\right] $,$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      0\\
      0\\
1
    \end{array}
\right] $} & $Q$={$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      1\\
      0\\
0
    \end{array}
\right] $,$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      0\\
      1\\
0
    \end{array}
\right] $,$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      0\\
      0\\
2
    \end{array}
\right] $}

Then  $P \neq Q $,but the space spanned by vectors of both these sets is $\mathbb R^3$.Hence,statement (1) is **NOT TRUE** in  general.

> (2) Consider vector space $\mathbb R^2$.

Now,consider the set $T$={$A= \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      1\\
      0
    \end{array}
\right] $,B=$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      0\\
      1
    \end{array}
\right] $,C=$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      2\\
      3
    \end{array}
\right] $},

$ A$ & $B$ are linearly independent,but $C=2A+3B$ which means the set $T$ is linearly dependent.Hence,statement (2) is **NOT TRUE** in general.

Answer (score 0):

**I.**

Is $L$ a linear transformation?  If so then think about [what must be true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Definition_and_first_consequences) for it to do so.  Does a linear transformation have to be invective? (hint: recall that all linear transformations have matrix representations)

Does $\bar{u} =\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} = \bar{v}?$

Yet, consider the linear transformation represented by the matrix: $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} $

Note that $A\bar{u} = A\bar{v} = \bar{0}$

**II.**

As to the second the question is being tricky, reread it carefully and think about how set containment works.  If $A \subset B$ does it follow that $A = B$ ?

Comment: I think "L" represents Linear span. Actually it is not mentioned in the question but the theory of book says linear span.